# How to set only one session per tab browser?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I want to restrict login users to only one session - even around browser tabs. If user loaded the page in another tab will be not logged in it, when log on - all other sessions will be destroyed.

How to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-restricted-sessions/0.1.2  Even if it's not exactly what you want to do, you could understand how to deal with the sessions in the source code. Sorry, I can't help more. Interesting question though!